# Why python interpreter not using venv

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I set up virtual env in my pycharm and i have interpreter of python in that venv and my console shows me that im using that but for some reason i still have packages of my main interpreter

How can i solve that?

This is my venv interpreter and im using it
[image]

But for some reason in terminal i still has previous intrepreter from another project [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: WSL2 has different Python installation than Windows. Use `cmd.exe` or `ps1.exe`. Not `bash.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that terminal, you can run `which python3` (outside of the Python REPL). You should see it's not your Desktop folder's venv python...

You need to use `cmd.exe` for the terminal. Then you need to invoke the `activate.bat` file of the venv in that folder before running `py3`/`python3` or `pip` commands.

Otherwise, use Pycharm's built-in pip management dialog which should automatically link to the project interpreter, rather than modify PyCharm terminal settings for *all projects*.